# Adicionar +1 à um Id ao adicionar campos dinamicamente

Tags: javascript

Qual comando se usa em JavaScript para adicionar +1 a um nome de uma id de um determinado campo em uma tabela?

Dinamicamente adiciono `tr` e nessa `tr` um campo tem um script que cria uma nova `tr` com os mesmo campos da anterior. Como faço pra nesse novo campo incluir no nome da id do campo +1.

Exemplo:

```
id = nome
```

Ao clicar em adicionar 3 vezes ele cria:

```
id = nome1
id = nome2
id = nome3
```

Sou leigo em JavaScript estou com dificuldade para encontrar o comando que seta a id da tabela e adiciona a variável ao lado do nome, que vai com um contador a cada adicionar incluindo +1.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode concatenar o nome com um contador:

```js
var cont = 1;
var nome = 'Teste';
function mostrar(){
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = nome + cont++;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="mostrar()">Exibir</button>
<br/>
<label id="res"></label>
```